# Working with Wikidata using their REST interface and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, wikidata

I am trying to push a value into Wikidata using their REST interface and PowerShell.

The code I have written on the face of it seems to run without error (as far as I can see) but no changes are made to wikidata as a result

```
   $AppToken = 'tokengoeshere' 
   $headers = @{
   "accept" = "application/json"
   Authorization = "Bearer $AppToken"
   #"If-Match" = "`"1276705620`""
   #"If-Unmodified-Since" = "Sat, 06 Jun 2020 16:38:47 GMT"
   #"If-None-Match" = "`"1276705620`""
   }
   $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri              "https://wikidata.org/w/rest.php/wikibase/v0/entities/items/Q13835647/statements" `
   -Method Post `
   -Headers $headers `
   -ContentType "application/json" `
   -Body "{`n  `"statement`": {`n    `"rank`": `"normal`",`n    `"property`": {`n      `"id`":    `"P1113`"`n    },`n    `"value`": {`n      `"content`": `"10`",`n      `"type`": `"value`"`n    },`n    `"qualifiers`": [],`n    `"references`": []`n  },`n  `"tags`": [`n    `"mobile edit`",`n    `"external tool edit`"`n  ],`n  `"bot`": true,`n  `"comment`": `"API edit adding the mumber of     episodes based on its RSS feed`"`n}"
```

I was expecting that it would add the statement "number of episodes" (P1113) with the value "10" but the record didn't change and nothing appeared in my "contributions" (recent changes) log.

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: Can you provide the $response details ?